# Grouping values in pandas into on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with an index of 'assigned' and value of 'ticket_number':

```
                    ticket_number
assigned                         
person1                    1
person1                    2
person2                    3
```

I am trying to group the ticket numbers by their common index, so that I can have unique indices.  I'm aiming to get it into a format like below that represents the one-to-many relationships:

```
                    ticket_number
assigned                         
person1                    1
                           2
person2                    3
```

Ultimate goal is to run it through the to_json() to get the below output:

```
{
    "ticket_number": {
        "person1": { "1","2" },
        "person2": "3",
    }
}
```

It seems like one of the orient parameters in `to_json()` would accommodate for this, but none yield the results that I am looking for.

How do I group the values within a common index , so that there is only one occurrence of the index and each index entry contains the set of values associated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the `DataFrame.groupby` method.

```
df.groupby(df.index).agg(lambda x: list(x))     

         ticket_number
assigned              
person1         [1, 2]
person2            [3]
```

And then on the whole resulting dataframe, a `Dataframe.to_json()`

```
df.groupby(df.index).agg(lambda x: list(x)).to_json()
'{"ticket_number":{"person1":[1, 2],"person2":[3]}}'
```

Linted:

```
{
    "ticket_number": {
        "person1": [1, 2],
        "person2": [3]
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  I did poke at the groupby function earlier, but missed the agg(...) part of it.  Thanks!